# Swapping chainrings on old ultegra crank

Tags: chainring, replacement

I have a 2002 Ultegra 9-speed triple with 52/39/30(?) chainrings. I swapped out the inner two chainrings twice and kept the original crank and 52-tooth ring. The 52t ring only gets used going downhill and weighing in at 134#, I don't put much pressure on it.

Are there ultegra quality replacements available, or do I need to update the crank+rings?

Comment: Is it not a standard 130 BCD crank? I would of thought so. If it is then there's millions to choose from.

Comment: All you need to do is measure BCD (directions are on http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_bo-z.html#bcd ,or just take the chainring to your LBS), and you can just bolt on another one with the same number of bolts and dimension (it is probably 130, but might be 110 - you can either measure this or google the Shimano Techdoc for the crank). There are tons of manufacturers who then make good quality chainrings (you can even get ultegra chainrings if it makes you feel better).

Comment: Gad, 2002 is "old"???!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your model number for the crank is most likely fc-6700 (EDIT: FC-6500). Double check on the inside of the end of the crankarm for this ID. If this is the correct number, just search 'fc-6700 chainring' in your favorite search engine and plenty of product results will show up.

Comment: If the bike is from 2002, it's most certainly not 6700 series Ultegra, since that was released in 2009!

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was confused because that era of Dura Ace was 7700, and I figured the Ultegra stuff was therefore 6700. Should have double checked. Thanks.